# xRDP - listening socket is in wrong state we terminate listener, invalid x.509 certificate path defined..., Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, rdp

I'm using `Lubuntu 16.04` and `xRDP`. My first machine is `192.168.0.10` and is a rdp server, where `xRDP` is installed, my second machine is `192.168.0.11`, where I have `Remmina` as my RDP client.

I have a problem while connecting from `Remmina` to `xRDP`. Here are the errors:

```
root@vm:/home/student1# service xrdp status
● xrdp.service - xrdp (X Remote Desktop Protocol) protocol server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since nie 2017-02-05 23:02:23 CET; 6s ago
     Docs: man:xrdp(8)
           man:xrdp.ini(5)
  Process: 6309 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/xrdp $XRDP_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6301 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh /usr/share/xrdp/socksetup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6313 (xrdp)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/xrdp.service
           └─6313 /usr/sbin/xrdp

lut 05 23:02:21 vm systemd[1]: Starting xrdp (X Remote Desktop Protocol) protocol server...
lut 05 23:02:22 vm systemd[1]: xrdp.service: PID file /run/xrdp/xrdp.pid not readable (yet?) after start: No such file or dir
lut 05 23:02:23 vm systemd[1]: Started xrdp (X Remote Desktop Protocol) protocol server.
root@vm:/home/student1# service xrdp status
● xrdp.service - xrdp (X Remote Desktop Protocol) protocol server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since nie 2017-02-05 23:02:23 CET; 15s ago
     Docs: man:xrdp(8)
           man:xrdp.ini(5)
  Process: 6309 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/xrdp $XRDP_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6301 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh /usr/share/xrdp/socksetup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6313 (xrdp)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/xrdp.service
           ├─6313 /usr/sbin/xrdp
           └─6364 /usr/sbin/xrdp

lut 05 23:02:21 vm systemd[1]: Starting xrdp (X Remote Desktop Protocol) protocol server...
lut 05 23:02:22 vm systemd[1]: xrdp.service: PID file /run/xrdp/xrdp.pid not readable (yet?) after start: No such file or dir
lut 05 23:02:23 vm systemd[1]: Started xrdp (X Remote Desktop Protocol) protocol server.
lut 05 23:02:34 vm xrdp[6313]: (6313)(140690527951680)[INFO ] A connection received from: 0.0.0.0 port 59046
lut 05 23:02:34 vm xrdp[6313]: (6313)(140690527951680)[INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: 0.0.0.0:59046 - s
lut 05 23:02:34 vm xrdp[6364]: (6364)(140690527951680)[INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socke
lut 05 23:02:34 vm xrdp[6364]: (6364)(140690527951680)[CORE ] WARNING: Invalid x.509 certificate path defined, default path w
lut 05 23:02:34 vm xrdp[6364]: (6364)(140690527951680)[WARN ] Invalid X.509 certificate path defined, default path will be us
lut 05 23:02:34 vm xrdp[6364]: (6364)(140690527951680)[DEBUG] xrdp_000018dc_wm_login_mode_event_00000001
lut 05 23:02:34 vm xrdp[6364]: (6364)(140690527951680)[WARN ] local keymap file for 0x10415 found and doesn't match built in 
root@vm:/home/student1# service xrdp status
● xrdp.service - xrdp (X Remote Desktop Protocol) protocol server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since nie 2017-02-05 23:02:23 CET; 1min 11s ago
     Docs: man:xrdp(8)
           man:xrdp.ini(5)
  Process: 6309 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/xrdp $XRDP_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6301 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh /usr/share/xrdp/socksetup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6313 (xrdp)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/xrdp.service
           └─6313 /usr/sbin/xrdp

lut 05 23:02:44 vm xrdp[6416]: (6416)(140690527951680)[INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socke
lut 05 23:02:44 vm xrdp[6416]: (6416)(140690527951680)[CORE ] WARNING: Invalid x.509 certificate path defined, default path w
lut 05 23:02:44 vm xrdp[6416]: (6416)(140690527951680)[WARN ] Invalid X.509 certificate path defined, default path will be us
lut 05 23:02:45 vm xrdp[6364]: (6364)(140690527951680)[DEBUG] return value from xrdp_mm_connect 0
lut 05 23:02:45 vm xrdp[6416]: (6416)(140690527951680)[INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: 0.0.0.0:40286 - s
lut 05 23:02:45 vm xrdp[6364]: (6364)(140690527951680)[INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: 0.0.0.0:59046 - s
lut 05 23:02:45 vm xrdp[6364]: (6364)(140690527951680)[DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
lut 05 23:02:45 vm xrdp[6364]: (6364)(140690527951680)[INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: 0.0.0.0:3389 - so
lut 05 23:02:45 vm xrdp[6416]: (6416)(140690527951680)[ERROR] Listening socket is in wrong state we terminate listener
lut 05 23:02:46 vm xrdp[6364]: (6364)(140690527951680)[ERROR] Listening socket is in wrong state we terminate listener
```

And here are my config files: (`/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini`)

```
[globals]
# xrdp.ini file version number
ini_version=1

bitmap_cache=yes
bitmap_compression=yes
port=3389
allow_channels=true
max_bpp=32
fork=yes
# minimum security level allowed for client
# can be 'none', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'fips'
crypt_level=high
# security layer can be 'tls', 'rdp' or 'negotiate'
# for client compatible layer
security_layer=rdp
# X.509 certificate and private key
# openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
certificate=cert.pem
key_file=key.pem

# regulate if the listening socket use socket option tcp_nodelay
# no buffering will be performed in the TCP stack
tcp_nodelay=yes

# regulate if the listening socket use socket option keepalive
# if the network connection disappear without close messages the connection will be closed
tcp_keepalive=yes

#tcp_send_buffer_bytes=32768
#tcp_recv_buffer_bytes=32768

#
# colors used by windows in RGB format
#

blue=009cb5
grey=dedede
#black=000000
#dark_grey=808080
#blue=08246b
#dark_blue=08246b
#white=ffffff
#red=ff0000
#green=00ff00
#background=626c72
#autorun=xrdp1
#hidelogwindow=yes

# when true, userid/password *must* be passed on cmd line
# require_credentials=yes

# set a default entry for autorun if the client send login and pass directly
autorun=xrdp1

bulk_compression=yes

# You can set the PAM error text in a gateway setup (MAX 256 chars)
#pamerrortxt=change your password according to policy at http://url
new_cursors=yes
allow_multimon=true

# fastpath - can be set to input / output / both / none
use_fastpath=both
#
# configure login screen
#

# Login Screen Window Title
#ls_title=My Login Title

# top level window background color in RGB format
ls_top_window_bg_color=009cb5

# width and height of login screen
ls_width=350
ls_height=430

# login screen background color in RGB format
ls_bg_color=dedede

# optional background image filename (bmp format).
#ls_background_image=

# logo
# full path to bmp-file or file in shared folder
ls_logo_filename=
ls_logo_x_pos=55
ls_logo_y_pos=50

# for positioning labels such as username, password etc
ls_label_x_pos=30
ls_label_width=60

# for positioning text and combo boxes next to above labels
ls_input_x_pos=110
ls_input_width=210

# y pos for first label and combo box
ls_input_y_pos=220

# OK button
ls_btn_ok_x_pos=142
ls_btn_ok_y_pos=370
ls_btn_ok_width=85
ls_btn_ok_height=30

# Cancel button
ls_btn_cancel_x_pos=237
ls_btn_cancel_y_pos=370
ls_btn_cancel_width=85
ls_btn_cancel_height=30

[Logging]
LogFile=xrdp.log
LogLevel=DEBUG
EnableSyslog=1
SyslogLevel=DEBUG
# LogLevel and SysLogLevel could by any of: core, error, warning, info or debug

[channels]
# Channel names not listed here will be blocked by XRDP.
# You can block any channel by setting its value to false.
# IMPORTANT! All channels are not supported in all use
# cases even if you set all values to true.
# You can override these settings on each session type
# These settings are only used if allow_channels=true
rdpdr=true
rdpsnd=true
drdynvc=true
cliprdr=true
rail=true
xrdpvr=true
tcutils=true

# for debugging xrdp, in section xrdp1, change port=-1 to this:
# port=/var/run/xrdp/sockdir/xrdp_display_10

# for debugging xrdp, add following line to section xrdp1
# chansrvport=/var/run/xrdp/sockdir/xrdp_chansrv_socket_7210

[xrdp1]
name=rdp-pls-connect
lib=libxup.so
username=test
password=test
ip=127.0.0.1
port=3389
xserverbpp=24
code=20

[xrdp2]
name=sesman-Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
#delay_ms=2000

[xrdp3]
name=console
lib=libvnc.so
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5900
username=na
password=ask
#delay_ms=2000

[xrdp4]
name=vnc-any
lib=libvnc.so
ip=ask
port=ask5900
username=na
password=ask
#pamusername=asksame
#pampassword=asksame
#pamsessionmng=127.0.0.1
#delay_ms=2000

[xrdp5]
name=sesman-any
lib=libvnc.so
ip=ask
port=-1
username=ask
password=ask
#delay_ms=2000

[xrdp6]
name=rdp-any
lib=librdp.so
ip=ask
port=ask3389

[xrdp7]
name=neutrinordp-any
lib=libxrdpneutrinordp.so
ip=ask
port=ask3389
username=ask
password=ask

[Session manager]
name=Session manager
lib=libxup.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
xserverbpp=24
code=20

# You can override the common channel settings for each session type
#channel.rdpdr=true
#channel.rdpsnd=true
#channel.drdynvc=true
#channel.cliprdr=true
#channel.rail=true
#channel.xrdpvr=true
```

`/etc/xrdp/sesman.ini`:

```
[Globals]
ListenAddress=127.0.0.1
ListenPort=3389
EnableUserWindowManager=1
UserWindowManager=startwm.sh
DefaultWindowManager=startwm.sh

[Security]
AllowRootLogin=1
MaxLoginRetry=4
TerminalServerUsers=tsusers
TerminalServerAdmins=tsadmins
# When AlwaysGroupCheck = false access will be permitted
# if the group TerminalServerUsers is not defined.
AlwaysGroupCheck = false

[Sessions]

## X11DisplayOffset - x11 display number offset
# Type: integer
# Default: 10
X11DisplayOffset=10

## MaxSessions - maximum number of connections to an xrdp server
# Type: integer
# Default: 0
MaxSessions=1

## KillDisconnected - kill disconnected sessions
# Type: integer
# Default: 0
# if 1, true, or yes, kill session after 60 seconds
KillDisconnected=0

## IdleTimeLimit - when to disconnect idle sessions
# Type: integer
# Default: 0
# if not zero, the seconds without mouse or keyboard input before disconnect
# not complete yet
IdleTimeLimit=0

## DisconnectedTimeLimit - when to kill idle sessions
# Type: integer
# Default: 0
# if not zero, the seconds before a disconnected session is killed
# min 60 seconds
DisconnectedTimeLimit=0

## Policy - session allocation policy
# Type: enum [ "Default" | "UBD" | "UBI" | "UBC" | "UBDI" | "UBDC" ]
# Default: Xrdp:<User,BitPerPixel> and Xvnc:<User,BitPerPixel,DisplaySize>
# "UBD" session per <User,BitPerPixel,DisplaySize>
# "UBI" session per <User,BitPerPixel,IPAddr>
# "UBC" session per <User,BitPerPixel,Connection>
# "UBDI" session per <User,BitPerPixel,DisplaySize,IPAddr>
# "UBDC" session per <User,BitPerPixel,DisplaySize,Connection>
Policy=Default

[Logging]
LogFile=xrdp-sesman.log
LogLevel=DEBUG
EnableSyslog=1
SyslogLevel=DEBUG

[X11rdp]
param0=X11rdp
param1=-bs
param2=-ac
param3=-nolisten
param4=tcp
param5=-uds

[Xvnc]
param0=Xvnc
param1=-bs
param2=-ac
param3=-nolisten
param4=tcp
param5=-localhost
param6=-dpi
param7=96

[Xorg]
param0=Xorg
param1=-config
param2=xrdp/xorg.conf
param3=-noreset
param4=-ac
param5=-nolisten
param6=tcp
param7=-retro

[Chansrv]
# drive redirection, defaults to .xrdp_client if not set
FuseMountName=.thinclient_drives

[SessionVariables]
PULSE_SCRIPT=/etc/xrdp/pulse/default.pa
```

Can somebody please help? Notice that errors also say about wrong path to certificate, `WARNING: Invalid x.509 certificate path defined, default path ...` but I have both the key and ert in the same directory as the config files, namely `/etc/xrdp` so I don't think it is a real issue.